# SSIS : Converting DT_NTEXT to image file

Tags: sql-server, image, ssis, type-conversion, blob

I am running an SSIS file that read from DataSource to convert it into Image File
for that I am using "Export Column" and everything seems to be alright except that generated files cannot be opened (as they are not images)
The file name is ending with JPG but the end result a file with real size but cannot be opened

The source column in of type DT_NTEXT

I wonder what could be wrong that cause this

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there is a DT_IMAGE DataType

Comment: @MiguelH Cant Convert DT_NTEXT to DT_IMAGE, get error for that

Comment: What is the error? Could you share some sample data for reference?